# MVC4 edit a complex object in multiple forms with a single submit button

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc-4

There is a huge object which I need to edit in different tabs. Each tab is a partial view with a single form inside. Is it possible to submit data from all the partial forms with a single submit button? I would like to have combined model object in my POST action method to save it further.

Comment: Why not put the form tag outside the partial views?

Comment: Really, why not :-) Thanks, Blade0rz

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your page, just make sure that all your partial views are wrapped by the main form:

```
@model MyNamespace.BigModel;

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    <!-- Other tab code would go around here -->
    @Html.Partial("Partial1", BigModel)
    @Html.Partial("Partial2", BigModel)
    @Html.Partial("Partial3", BigModel)
    <!-- Other tab code would go around here -->
}
```

Then a submit button anywhere within the form would submit all the data.

Comment: Ok, I tried it. @Html.Partial("Partial1", BigModel) worked for me, otherwise BigModel.SmallerPartN is null in POST action method.

Answer (score 0):

You could use something on the client side to do this (for example using jQuery):

```
$('#button-to-submit-everything').click(function () {
    $('form').submit();
});
```

This would submit an individual post to each partial view.

If you only want one post then I believe you would need to have only one form encompassing all of your partial views.